# is there a way to terminate a function inside another function in python

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am making Snake and I want it to move in the x direction and in the y direction (separately).

I made a class and gave it a method of move up, down, and left, if I bind the window with the up arrow key the function up should work and I did the same with all the other arrows, but it turns out if I press up then down, the function up is working at the same time as down.

Is there a way or me to stop the function down when I press the up arrow key?

```
count=1
from time import *
direction=None
eaten=False
WIDGIT_SIZE=40
def declareup():
    global direction
    if count==1:
        direction="up"
def declaredown():
    global direction
    if count==1:
        direction="down"
def declareright():
    global direction
    if count==1:
        direction="right"
def declareleft():
    global direction
    if count==1:
        direction="left"

class Snake():
    def __init__(self,canvas,topx,topy):
        self.cavas=canvas
        self.topx=topx
        self.topy=topy
        self.bottomx=WIDGIT_SIZE
        self.bottomy=WIDGIT_SIZE
        self.snake=self.cavas.create_rectangle(self.topx,self.topy,self.bottomx,self.bottomy,fill='green')
        self.squares = [self.snake]
    def movedown(self,event):
        global eaten
        self.topy+=40
        self.bottomy+=40
        if not eaten:
            self.cavas.delete(self.squares[-1])
        self.newsnake = self.cavas.create_rectangle(self.topx, self.topy, self.bottomx, self.bottomy, fill='green')
        self.squares.append(self.newsnake)
        window.after(100, self.movedown, event)
        window.update()
    def moveup(self,event):
        global eaten
        self.topy-=40
        self.bottomy-=40

        print(self.topy,self.bottomy)
        if not eaten:
            self.cavas.delete(self.squares[-1])
        self.newsnake = self.cavas.create_rectangle(self.topx, self.topy, self.bottomx, self.bottomy, fill='green')
        self.squares.append(self.newsnake)
        window.after(100,self.moveup,event)

        window.update()
    def moveright(self,event):
        global eaten
        self.topx+=40
        self.bottomx+=40
        if not eaten:
            self.cavas.delete(self.squares[-1])
        self.newsnake = self.cavas.create_rectangle(self.topx, self.topy, self.bottomx, self.bottomy, fill='green')
        self.squares.append(self.newsnake)
        window.after(100, self.moveright, event)
        window.update()
    def moveleft(self,event):
        global eaten
        self.topx-=40
        self.bottomx-=40
        if not eaten:
            self.cavas.delete(self.squares[-1])
        self.newsnake = self.cavas.create_rectangle(self.topx, self.topy, self.bottomx, self.bottomy, fill='green')
        self.squares.append(self.newsnake)
        window.after(100, self.moveleft, event)
        window.update()




from tkinter import *
window=Tk()

window.geometry('520x520')
window.config(background='black')
window.resizable(False,False)
canvas=Canvas(window,width=520,height=520,bg='black')
gamesnake=Snake(canvas,0,0)

window.bind('<Down>',gamesnake.movedown)
window.bind('<Up>',gamesnake.moveup)
window.bind('<Right>',gamesnake.moveright)
window.bind('<Left>',gamesnake.moveleft)
canvas.pack()
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: No, but you could have a single loop that moves the snake, and only set the direction in the event handlers. That way you will be able to stop the snake moving after you release a key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you can't and shouldn't terminate functions. It's because you scheduled functions in the key event handlers and they accumulates.

So, do like this.

```
...
class Snake():
    def __init__(self,canvas,topx,topy):
        ...
        self.next_action = None
        def update():
            if self.next_action:
                self.next_action(None)
            window.after(100, update)
        update()

    def movedown(self,event):
        ...
        self.squares.append(self.newsnake)
        window.update()
        self.next_action = self.movedown

    def moveup(self,event):
        ...
        self.squares.append(self.newsnake)
        window.update()
        self.next_action = self.moveup
...
```